# Concat int array field inside an array of object into one string field in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, aggregate, string-concatenation

I would like to concat int array field values inside an array of objects into one string field after dividing them (by 10).

Heres the existing document format:

```
{ 
  "no" : "2020921008981",  
  "date" : ISODate("2020-04-01T05:19:02.263+0000"), 
  "sale" : { 
   "soldItems" : [
       {
         "itemRefId" : "5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24", 
         "soldPrice" : NumberInt(800), 
       },
       {
         "itemRefId" : "5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b25", 
         "soldPrice" : NumberInt(1000), 
       }
     ] 
   }
 }
```

Expected result :

```
{ 
  "no" : "2020921008981",  
  "date" : ISODate("2020-04-01T05:19:02.263+0000"),  
  "priceList" : "8.0 \n 10.0"
}
```

The attempt with $reduce :

```
 priceList: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$sale.soldItems.soldPrice",
                initialValue: "",
                in: {
                    $cond: [ { "$eq": [ { $toString: { $divide: [ "$$value", 10 ] } }, "" ] }, "$$this", { $concat: [ { $toString: { $divide: [ "$$value", 10 ] } }, "\n", "$$this" ] } ]
                }
            }
        }
```

But end up getting `"errmsg" : "$divide only supports numeric types, not string and double"` error. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have posted an answer based on the requirement. See if that works. Also in your expected o/p ... 800/10 is 80 not 8.0 and similarly 1000/10 is 100 not 10. Did u mean to dive by 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
db.case.aggregate([
    {
        $set: {
            priceList: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$sale.soldItems.soldPrice",
                            in: { $toString: { $divide: ["$$this", 10] } }
                        }
                    },
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: { $concat: ["$$value", "$$this", " \n "] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            no: 1,
            date: 1,
            priceList: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks buddy this works as intended. I just put a question for a new scenario related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173858/concat-int-and-string-array-fields-which-are-in-different-arrays

Comment: @dineshalwis i'll have a look at it as soon as i can. what platform you building your app in? node/php/.net? just curious :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following aggregation query, where the idea is to:

- First divide the field `soldPrice` by 10 or required divisor using [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)
- Convert it into string and concat using [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) and [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)
- the appender `\n` gets appended after each reduce op,remove that from the end using [`$rtrim`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rtrim/)
- create the new field using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "itemPriceList": {
        $rtrim: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$salesOrder.purchaseItems",
              initialValue: "",
              in: {
                $concat: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $toString: {
                      $divide: [
                        "$$this.soldPrice",
                        10
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "\n"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          chars: "\n"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "caseNumber": "2020921008981",
    "itemPriceList": "80\n100",
    "salesOrder": {
      "purchaseItems": [
        {
          "itemRefId": "5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24",
          "soldPrice": 800
        },
        {
          "itemRefId": "5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b25",
          "soldPrice": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    "startTime": ISODate("2016-05-18T16:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

[Plaground Test Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aX4AAKWKLTa)