# How to $lookup by avoiding null values in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In here i'm using $lookup to to a left join from other collections, the query works fine but when some records missing values it returns

`errmsg : $in requires an array as a second argument, found: null`

Heres the querying document structure :

```
{
 "no" : "2020921008981",
 "sale" : {
  "soldItems" : [
    {
        "itemId" : "5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24", 
    },

    {
        "itemId" : "5b55ac7f0550de00215584re", 
    }
  ], 
 "bills" : [
    {
        "billNo" : "2020921053467", 
        "insurancePlanId" : "160", 
    },

    {
        "billNo" : "2020921053467", 
        "insurancePlanId" : "170", 
     }
   ],
   "visitIds" : [
   5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24, 5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24
   ]

  }
}
```

the query :

```
db.case.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "insurance",
        let: { ipids: "$sale.bill.insurancePlanId" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $unwind: "$coveragePlans"
            },
            {
                $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$coveragePlans._id", "$$ipids"] } }
            },
            {
                $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 }
            }
        ],
        as: "insurances"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "item",
        let: { iid: "$salesOrder.purchaseItems.itemRefId" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ["$_id", {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$iid",
                                in: { $toObjectId: "$$this" }
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "items"
      }
  }
])
```

insurance collection :

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b55aca20550de00210a6d25"), 
  "name" : "HIJKL" 
  "coveragePlans" : [
    {
      "_id" : "160", 
      "name" : "UVWZ", 
    }, 
    { 
    "_id" : "161", 
    "name" : "LMNO", 
    }
   ]
 },
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b55aca20550de00210a6d25"),  
  "name" : "WXYZ"
  "coveragePlans" : [
   {
    "_id" : "169", 
    "name" : "5ABC", 
   }, 
   { 
    "_id" : "170", 
    "name" : "4XYZ", 
    }
  ]
}
```

item collection :

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b55ac7f0550de00210a3b24"), 
  "code" : "ABCDE"
},
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b55ac7f0550de00215584re"), 
  "code" : "PQRST" 
}
```

How to avoid this and do null checks effectively before pipe-lining into the next stages? Tried with `{ $match: { "fieldName": { $exists: true, $ne: null } } }` but it returns mongo error regarding the format. If its the way to go please mention the stage i should put that.. Thanks in advance

Comment: you seem to have a typo in your let variable : ipids: "$sales.bill.insurancePlanId", but 'sale' in your scheme

Comment: easiest thing to do would be to not set `null` when inserting the data into the database. instead set a blank array `[]` as the value in that field.

Comment: @matthPen corrected it thanks

Comment: Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ, well thats a thing that i have no control of ;)

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: @matthPen no it was just a typo i had made when putting the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator

```
let: { ipids: {$ifNull:["$sale.bill.insurancePlanId", [] ]} },
```

**EDIT:** To skip empty `"$salesOrder.purchaseItems.itemRefId"` values

```
let: { iid: {$filter: {input:"$salesOrder.purchaseItems.itemRefId", cond:{$ne:["$$this", ""]}}} },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
the previous error went away, but now this occurs. `errmsg : Failed to parse objectId  in $convert with no onError value: Invalid string length for parsing to OID, expected 24 but found 0`

Comment: @dineshalwis I've updated my answer, update your second lookup `iid` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can get around that by not using `$in`.

It looks like this `$map` is executed separately for every document in the `items` collection.  If you were to run  the map in an `$addFields` stage, you could used the simple form of lookup to match the added field to `_id`, which would automagically handle missing, `null`, and array.

Remove the added field with a `$project` stage if necessary.

```
db.case.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: "insurance",
        let: { ipids: "$sale.bill.insurancePlanId" },
        pipeline: [
            {$unwind: "$coveragePlans"},
            {$match: { $expr: { $in: ["$coveragePlans._id", "$$ipids"] } }},
            {$project: { _id: 0, name: 1 }}
        ],
        as: "insurances"
    }}
    {$addFields:{
        matchArray:{$map: {
                       input: "$$iid",
                       in: { $toObjectId: "$$this" }
        }}
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "item",
        localField: "matchArray",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as: "items"
    }},
    {$project:{
        arrayField: 0 
    }}
])
```